# Why no error on multiple declarations of same structure variable

Tags: c, structure

I started doing programs on structures. I am confused about declaring structures itself because of the reason that it is allowing multiple declarations of same variable, which is not common in c.

Let us consider the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct {
        int x;
        int y;
}u, v;

int main()
{
        struct {int x; int y;} u = {3, 4},  v = {5, 6};
/*      struct {int x; int y;} u, v*/
        printf("%d\n", u.x);
        printf("%d\n", v.y);

        return 0;
}
```

In general, C disallows multiple declaration of same variable, here also it does if I don't comment out the second statement in main. But my doubt is that why it is neglecting multiple declaration of same variables if one is inside main and not other?

Comment: The inner `u` is different from the outer `u`. All the both have in common is the name, with the inner `u` shadowing (hiding) the outer `u`. Same for `v`.

Comment: `char x; void foo(int x) {{float x; {double x;}}}` is valid. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Variables in some scope are allowed to **shadow** variables in an enclosing scope. So both variables exist, but if you write `u` inside `main`, it refers to the one declared in `main`.

Don't write such code, it's confusing, although legal.

Comment: So, is u and v written outside main are global variables?

Comment: The correct term in C would be *file-scoped* variables. That's probably what you mean by *global*.

Answer (score 2):

C allows multiple declaration of same variable if they are declared in different scope. `u` declared in `main`, having block scope, will hide the declaration of `u` declared globally.

§6.2.1 (p4):

> [...] Within the inner scope, the identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the entity declared in the outer scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.